# how does Profile information should be provided so Passport.js can use it?

Tags: php, node.js, oauth, passport.js

I'm trying to implement a custom OAuth2 provider for a website, using [oauth2-server-php](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php), to authenticate a node.js client using Passport.

The implemented endpoints (e.g. authorize, token) are pretty much the same as described in [this oauth2-server-php tutorial](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/).

Inside my node.js application, I use Passport's oauth2 strategy, using a configuration similar to this one (from the passport docs):

```
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
    clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/example/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ exampleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

As you can see, it handles the received info with `function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)`.

And my question is: how do I need to provide (inside my custom oauth2 provider) the `profile` parameter, so Passport can access it? where does it *precisely* comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the `UserProfile` function like the Facebook strategy does:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L137